# Redirect loop after activating wordpress multisite feature

Tags: multisite

We have an existing wordpress-website which we want to use with the multisite feature now.

We have a development version of the whole website which is available under https://www-dev2.voipone.ch

During network-setup of the multisite feature we were forced to use the subdomain-structure with multisite. It's because a lot of content already exists and permalink structure would have to be changed otherwise.

I setup wp-config.php as follows

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www-dev2.voipone.ch');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'https://www-dev2.voipone.ch' );
```

I setup .htaccess as follows

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# uploaded ﬁles
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ﬁles/(.+) wp-includes/ms-ﬁles.php?ﬁle=$2 [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I already added some lines like the cookie-settings and NOBLOGREDIRECT to the wp-config which I found by searching for solutions.

Has anybody an idea why the website is in a redirect-loop?